# Draw with Tikz an image where two convexes are separated

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, draw

I am looking for a way to draw both these two pictures, which describes the separation of convexes.

[image: picture1] and [image: picture2]

I looked in some posts, but with no results.
Given my ignorance of the Tikz package, I can't give a draft code. So a great apology.

In advance,many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trying to find the precisely same picture somewhere may not be the most efficient strategy. It may be more efficient to look at the tutorial of pgfmanual, which describes very nicely how to draw such things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \draw[ultra thin] (-2,0) -- (4,0) (0,-2) -- (0,4);
 \draw (-0.5,3) -- (3,-0.5) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux)
 node[pos=0.7,sloped,above]{$x+W$}
 node[pos=0.8,sloped,below]{Hyper plane};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (aux) node[midway,below right]{$x$};
 \node[circle,draw,fill=gray,minimum size=2.4cm] at (-1,1.2) {$K$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \draw[dashed] (-2.5,3) -- (2.5,-0.5);
 \node[circle,draw,fill=gray,minimum size=2.4cm] at (1,2.4) {$K_2$};
 \draw[fill=gray,rounded corners] (-2,2) -- (-0.2,1) -- (0.2,-1) -- (-1.5,0) -- (-2.2,1.5) --cycle;
 \path (-2,2) --  (0.2,-1)  node[midway] {$K_1$};
 \draw[ultra thin] (-3,0) -- (3,0) (0,-2) -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

Comment: can you make K_1 and k_2 two squares?